# Enable scroll bars in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a windows forms application. In my application I have anchored controls to forms such that forms can be maximized and controls will get arranged accordingly. This application should support different DPI values.

I have set the anchors of some controls to bottom, right, and bottom-right. The AutoScroll property of the forms is set to true. When the DPI value is on default (96) controls work as expected. But the problem is if the screen loads in higher DPI (like 120), even though form scroll bars enabled, controls which are anchored to bottom and bottom-right cannot be seen.

Could anybody please advise me on this issue?

regards,
Eranga

Comment: I'm not sure what the description of your problem has got to do with scrollbars enabled or not. Are you saying the form behaves differently with and without scrollbars?

Comment: does this link help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841285/change-the-size-of-scrollbar-in-winforms?

Comment: @ Mr Lister: Yes sir. Controls which are anchored to right, bottom cannot be seen in the screen. They are set beyond the screen edges. If scroll bars can be enabled those can be displayed.

Answer (score 51):

Set `AutoScroll = True` In Form Properties

[image: Set AutoScroll = true on form]

Comment: This did not enable Horizontal scroll bar

Comment: @Pரதீப்  Horizontal bars are only enabled with it needs to be. if form is not long enough then Scroll Bars wont be visible.

Answer (score 14):

Create a `Panel` called `panel`, then do the following:

```
panel1.autoscroll  = true;
panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

Use this method to set scroll width and height:

```
panel1.SetAutoScrollMargin(int x,int y);
```

Answer (score 9):

It's an old post but the issue is ongoing and related posts just keep on arriving on `SO`!

I'm doing the necro thing here rather than addressing a more recent question only because it comes top of my [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=.net+windows+forms+scrollbar+not+visible)

The question is simple: **"why won't the damn scrollbars appear on my [`ScrollableControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)?"**

But there *can be no specific, definitive answer*. Because the causes are legion. Because whether or not scrollbars appear on a control depends:

- not only upon it's own properties settings
- but also upon the state of it's parent control
- and also the states of any child controls.

It's easy to fall into the trap of randomly twiddling prop-values until the cows come home. Or go on the i/webs &hope to find some `SO` foos. But oh dear. Here is a handful of related `SO` posts with an outstanding variety of proposed resolutions:

[Horizontal Scrollbar is not visible on DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218819/horizontal-scrollbar-is-not-visible-on-datagridview)

[Horizontal scrollbar not showing on my textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803301/horizontal-scrollbar-not-showing-on-my-textbox)

[How to set scroll bar in Windows form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313442/how-to-set-scroll-bar-in-windows-form)

[How to make scrollbars appear in a resizable panel when the contained control is too big for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222830/how-to-make-scrollbars-appear-in-a-resizable-panel-when-the-contained-control-is)

[Scrollable Form in c#, AutoScroll=true doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789197/scrollable-form-in-c-autoscroll-true-doesnt-work)

[How to get scrollbar in Panel in VB.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507228/how-to-get-scrollbar-in-panel-in-vb-net)

There are screen-shots of `VS-designer` property pages (like here) & even some extreme code-based solutions... my favourites:

[Add vertical scroll bar to panel in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090558/add-vertical-scroll-bar-to-panel-in-net)

[how to add Vscroll control to form in Visualbasic.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817251/how-to-add-vscroll-control-to-form-in-visualbasic-net)

/sighs/

---

### A general answer

..in the form of a *minimal* github solution in order to explore some of the .NET scrollbar voodoos:

https://github.com/violet313/TestWinForms/tree/Test1-Body-Panel

It's a `Visual Studio 2015` solution using the `.NET4.52 framework`.

In the solution i am trying to create a form that responds to some dynamic text data that is to be displayed. here's the basic lay-out i am ultimately seeking:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|      fixed-size form header       |            | 
------------------------------------|   side     |
|                                   |   panel    |
|      dynamic content panel        |   stuff    |
|                                   |            |
--------------------------------------------------
|      fixed-size form trailer                   |               
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want the form to:

- not be resizable by the user
- respond to the dynamic content by:

  - shrinking as small as possible down to a pre-determined minimum form-size.
  - growing up to a pre-determined maximum form-size; and providing appropriate scroll-bars on the dynamic content panel thereafter.

Grab it, go thro each of the (only 9 starting from 95dccc5)commits and then test *your* requirements in a sane & incremental fashion. be sure to branch whenever you make a dubious state-change.

Irl: maybe i'm a thicky but it took me over an hour reading the MSDNs trying (&failing) to figure-out the .NET forms control property contingencies. doing structured trial-and-error this way took me only 20mins to get what i wanted.

---

`y~bwc`

> i know this here is a  **yeaz ~but who cares?** but i had to get if off my chest. heh :
>  grrr. having to unlurk &answer this question arises out of my need to
>  profitably take on Microsoft contract work. paymasters can be
>  relatively (from a developer pov) non-technical and, having read lots
>  of stuff including the words: quick, simple, straight-forward, secure,
>  etc, come away with the impression that things .NETish is a stroll in
>  the park. My issue with this is that i would then have difficulty
>  trying to reasonably explain why they might need to pay me for n-day's
>  worth of work in order to get a simple scroll-bar to appear on a
>  responsive form. 
>  
>  
>  On this occasion, i never got that far. lol. i spent a few hours
>  wading thro the MSDN blahs trying to make it happen. and then yawned,
>  gave up, &moved on with a pragmatic implementation. which was
>  accepted. but it's now the w/end and i am an ocd fool who cannot let
>  things be.

Comment: plus one for your OCD :) which made you write a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

I was reading through [this page](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/winforms-scaling-at-large-dpi-settings-is-it-even-possible-) and i can say it provides an exact and easy solution to your problem!

I tested it and it worked well for me.

Instruction:

1. Add a manifest file to your project (**Project** --> **New Item**
   --> Select the manifest type)
2. Add the following XML into your app.manifest (may be another name):

```xml
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
   <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
             <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
   </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

3. Add the following C# code into the class where you call the component initialize (`InitializeComponent();`)

```c#
[DllImport("shcore.dll")]
static extern int SetProcessDpiAwareness(_Process_DPI_Awareness value);

enum _Process_DPI_Awareness
{
    Process_DPI_Unaware = 0,
    Process_System_DPI_Aware = 1,
    Process_Per_Monitor_DPI_Aware = 2
}
```

4. Now just add this code line above your initialize component method (by default `InitializeComponent();`)

```c#
SetProcessDpiAwareness(_Process_DPI_Awareness.Process_DPI_Unaware);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. From "Form" properties  Set AutoScroll = True:**
[image]
**2. Move any control to the lower right corner:**
[image]