# Add a scroll event to repaint form

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, and I am experimenting by placing a dot where a user clicks on a form. I am working with a 300 x 200 form with a maximum size of 640 x 480. Using the form's AutoScrollMinSize property, I set this maximum size:

```
this.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(640, 480);
```

I am able to place dots onto the form, but the dots disappear once I have scrolled out of the visible area. Since I created the scroll area manually, I am looking for a way to add a scroll event handler that will call this.Invalidate() to repaint the form whenever scrolling occurs. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(640, 480);

  vScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();
  vScrollBar1.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(this.vScrollBar1_Scroll);
}
```

And here is how I'm calling the event handler:

```
private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(Object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
   this.Invalidate();
}
```

I got this example from the Microsoft documentation, but the drawing is still disappearing when I scroll vertically, so I know the form is not repainting.

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: `Form` should have a `Scroll` event you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that VScrollBar control (which you never added to the form anyway).

Just override the OnScroll method of the form:

```
protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se) {
  base.OnScroll(se);
  this.Invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put your event in a deligate

and use 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitter.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.aspx

[How to set scroll bar in Windows form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313442/how-to-set-scroll-bar-in-windows-form)

and set

```
vScrollBar.visible = true and if it is in pannel or form set AutoScroll = true
```