# Scrollable Form in c#, AutoScroll=true doesn't work

Tags: c#, forms, scroll

What are the rules which I have to respect to make the Form scrollable...

I simple set the Property `AutoScroll` to true.
I also tried while `Auto Scroll` is true, to set `AutoSize` to true/false, but none of these worked... also tried to put Panel and added all components in there... still nothing...

Maybe using `V or HScrollBar` can help, but i really don't know how to link it with the Form...

```
form.AutoScroll = true;
formMainLayout.AutoScroll = true;
rootPanel.AutoScroll = true;
```

Comment: your child controls hide from form?

Comment: How do you mean 'child controls' hide from form?
if you mean this, form has this Controls.Add:
rootPanel, rootPanel has formMainLayout, and formMainLayout has all other Controls

Comment: I mean if your form size is (200,200). does any of your child controls exist beyond this?(beyond 200,200)

Comment: You have to give it a reason to show the scrollbars.  Make it smaller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content controls the scrolling.  The scrollbars do not appear unless they are needed.  Usually, there is a property available that you can set to force them to be visible always, and simply disabled until needed.

The `AutoScroll` property must be `true`, as you have already found.  But then the content of the scrollable control must force the parent control to display the scrollbars.  This part is up to how the controls are embedded within the parent.

Try these two experiments:

1. Place a `Panel` on your form and dock it to `Fill`.  Set the `AutoScroll` property of the Panel to `true`.  Into that panel, place a `TextBox` and set it to dock as `Fill` as well.  Also set `MultiLine` to `true`.  Run the application, and you will notice that the size of both is simply using the available space...no scrolling can occur because neither the `Panel`, nor its `TextBox` become larger than the space they occupy.
2. Perform the same steps as in #1, but this time, do not dock the `TextBox`.  Instead, set it to a large size, something that you know will be larger than the amount of `Panel` that is visible.  Running the application should now produce a scrolling `Panel`.

Hopefully this little test helps to demonstrate what is controlling the scroll on a form.

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure about what you meant with "the Form itself isn't a scrollable control". The form is as scrollable as any other control: autoscroll + conditions met (contained controls outside the boundaries) or vscrollbar/hscrollbar in it. Also, I am not too sure about the actual/direct applicability of what you say to answer the question "why when I set AutoScroll to true I don't see the bar?".

Comment: @varocarbas Your point is well taken.  I have removed that part of my answer.  In regard to the latter part of your comment, this is the question I am attempting to demonstrate an answer to:  "What are the rules which I have to respect to make the Form scrollable".

Comment: I set the root panel to Dock -> None... and it seems fine, but the problem is that I want some Controls to use all available size of the Form while some buttons to stay in height static and also width to use all available Form width... so far i achieved it with Dock -> Fill...

Comment: How ever, thank you it helped me somehow, i had to experiment with Size and Fills

Answer (score 8):

I was also having the same problem, I managed to fix it...
All the child controls inside the panel had a **Left** & **Right** anchor, and when I only set the anchor to Top, the scrollbars where working fine.

I am not sure as to why the **Left** and **Right** anchor (of the child controls) forces the panel not to show scrollbars.

But anyways... hope this will help anyone as of this date.

Answer (score 1):

The `AutoScroll` property should work fine, but most likely you are not using it right: the bar appears only when required. Example: minimum Y of the `Form` is 0 and minimum Y of one of the controls in it (a `TextBox`) is -20.

If you want to include a scroll bar no matter what (controls inside the boundaries of the form or not), you can also do it. Sample code ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) for a vertical scroll bar:

```
// Create and initialize a VScrollBar.
VScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();

// Dock the scroll bar to the right side of the form.
vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;

// Add the scroll bar to the form.
Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the properties for the parent panel.

1. Dock = Fill
2. Anchor = Top, Left
3. AutoScroll = true

That's it. Good luck! ^^

Answer (score 0):

note its for vertical scroll

1. Turn On auto scroll property of your Form. insert one panel and
   set panel width to the form width and panel height
   equal to length of your total content or may be 1300 or 1500 as
   required.
2. Place panel location as you want set panel anchor
   property to top. place your all
   content inside panel.

hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You have to add only this:

this.AdjustFormScrollbars(true);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).