# Horizontal scrollbar not showing on my textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar

On a Winform C# application, i display a textbox on my form.
This textbox will display one line, just one.
I would like to show and be abe to use an horizontal scrollbar.

I set the property "scrollbar" to horizontal : ScrollBar doesn't show.
I add WordWrap to false : ScrollBar doesn't show.
I add MultiLine to true ( even if one ligne ) : ScrollBar doesn't show.

My line displayed is a loter "longer" than the contrôle, so i really need a scrollbar :(

Here is the definition :

```
        this.TxtBox_ApercuFichier.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.TxtBox_ApercuFichier.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 30);
        this.TxtBox_ApercuFichier.Multiline = true;
        this.TxtBox_ApercuFichier.Name = "TxtBox_ApercuFichier";
        this.TxtBox_ApercuFichier.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Horizontal;
        this.TxtBox_ApercuFichier.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(702, 21);
        this.TxtBox_ApercuFichier.TabIndex = 12;
```

Even with wordwrap at false, it's the same result.
( My textbox is in a groupbox).

Any idea please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Regards,

Comment: WordWrap to true should work.  The Height should be larger than 21 pixels though.

Comment: WordWrap is already to true. I replace 21 by 25,same result :-( Maybe due to the groupbox?

Comment: To be clear: The scrollbar doesn't show even though your current text is longer? Also: If you want to display only one line, why set multiline=true??

Comment: How big is the GroupBox?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to do the following to get a horizontal scroll bar to display in a windows forms text box:

```
this.TxtBox_ApercuFichier.Multiline = true;
this.TxtBox_ApercuFichier.WordWrap = false;
this.TxtBox_ApercuFichier.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Horizontal;
```

You can then resize the text box to give the appearance of one line. You need to have `Multiline` enabled otherwise the height of the text box will be set to the text height (I can't seem to find an easy way to override this), hence you not being able to see the scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks guy ! It's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will set ScrollBar not visible and also the parent panel where its contained.

```
HScrollBar hScroller = textBox.HScrollBar;
hScroller.Visible = false;  
hScroller.Parent.Visible=false;
```

Comment: There is no HScrollBar property